# Do the C++ standards guarantee that unused private fields will influence sizeof?

Tags: c++, sizeof, language-lawyer

Consider the following struct:

```
class Foo {
    int a;
};
```

Testing in g++, I get that `sizeof(Foo) == 4` but is that guaranteed by the standard? Would a compiler be allowed to notice that `a` is an unused private field and remove it from the in-memory representation of the class (leading to a smaller sizeof)?

I don't expect any compilers to actually do that kind of optimization but this question popped up in a language lawyering discussion so now I'm curious.

Comment: In this case, certainly not: it's a standard-layout class, so the members can be accessed via `reinterpret_cast`. (I'm not sure whether or not it would be forbidden for more complex classes).

Comment: I imagine it'd get difficult very quickly for a compiler to verify the member isn't used (indirectly through pointer magic or in another translation unit, etc.)

Comment: In many compilers you can run code analysis that warns you for unused fields

Comment: I believe under the 'as-if' rule of optimization, the compiler certainly could remove a field, but only if it operates as-if it hadn't been removed. So if you ever used sizeof it couldn't remove the field. No standard reference though, so not an official answer.

Comment: By the way, I have seen the effect I speak of when reading disassembly of compiled code. A struct on the function stack disappeared into registers and had no memory location at all.

Comment: @MikeSeymour not sure that's a valid point, you could argue that a compiler can detect that you access the object indirectly and not perform the alleged optimization.

Comment: What if you were relying on the size of the class? For example if you wanted to pad a class out to a certain size. The fields would never be accessed (directly or indirectly), and `sizeof` might never be used either. However it could be that someone on the far side of a socket is expected to get objects of a certain size.

Comment: You can, [via tricks](http://bloglitb.blogspot.de/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html), access private data members of a class from outside, without Undefined Behaviour. As this can happen in any TU, the optimization could only be performed at link-time.

Comment: @ZanLynx I think you're basically right.  With the added proviso that the results of `sizeof` aren't really well specified, so I'm not sure that its presence is required to affect it.

Comment: @Dennis What does the results of `sizeof` have to do with what you're sending over the wire?  The only thing you can send over the wire is bytes, and if you haven't formatted them, there's absolutely no guarantee that the reader can do anything with them.

Comment: Not only sizeof(Class) should never be used, but also sizeof of any class that includes it as a member, or a derived class, or an array of all of teh above. There is no way a compiler can verify all of that.

Comment: I think it's generally illegal to completely optimize away unused members for the simple logic, that the addressof `&` of two distinct members need to produce different addresses. I wonderhowever whether a compiler would be allowed to reduce the size to 1 for instance.

Comment: @JamesKanze Could you not `reinterpret_cast` your class into a byte[] and then stuff it into a buffer for sending?

Comment: @Dennis Not if you expect it to be readable at the other end.

Comment: @JamesKanze Sorry for all the speculative ideas, but if on the other end your client has the same definition of your class, and they depended on the correct size then could they not read the expected number of bytes, and reinterpret_cast them back into the same class? I'd try it out myself but that seems like a lot of work!

Comment: @Dennis And what makes you think that the same definition of a `struct` will result in the same memory image.  I've seen it change from one release of the compiler to the next.  (And of course, as soon as the `struct` contains a pointer, either directly or indirectly, it can't possibly work.)  And of course (with regards to the OP, there's certainly no guarantee that `sizeof(Foo)` will be four; I've seen implementations where it would be 2 or 6, and of course, other values are possible as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't think this, but our gung-ho hypothetical programmer might... especially if he just coded and it worked, and he didn't think about portability. My point is that the compiler will not know how one component might be expecting to interact with another and so that could lead to problems if class sizes were interfered with by removing the "hidden" privates. It's a forced example though so probably not very likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't define a lot about memory layouts. The fundamental rule for this case is item 4 under section `9 Classes`:

> 4 Complete objects and member subobjects of class type shall have nonzero size. [ Note: Class objects can be assigned, passed as arguments to functions, and returned by functions (except objects of classes for which copying or moving has been restricted; see 12.8). Other plausible operators, such as equality comparison, can be defined by the user; see 13.5. — end note ]

Now there is one more restriction, though: Standard-layout classes. (no static elements, no virtuals, same visibility for all members) Section `9.2 Class members` requires layout compatibility between different classes for standard-layout classes. This prevents elimination of members from such classes.

For non-trivial non-standard-layout classes I see no further restriction in the standard. The exact behavior of sizeof(), reinterpret_cast(), ... are implementation defined (i.e. 5.2.10 "The mapping function is implementation-defined.").

Comment: The first quote just says the size can't be `0`, so it's moot. It could be 1. I also don't see how 9.2 disallows the element removal **if it's not used**. -1

Comment: The size not 0 quote is relevant as it is one of the few cases where the standard makes *any* requirement about size. From 9.2 I read that it miht have to be compatible with another class. that other class might use the element, thus there the element can't be removed. If it is removed in one, but not the other they are incompatible.

Comment: But I certainly don't claim mastering the standard.

Comment: Accessing the element indirectly still means accessing it. So the optimization couldn't be performed in that case anyway. That's why the argument pointless.

Comment: The standard imposes a number of restrictions on sizeof. See my answer for some of them.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes and no. A compiler could not exhibit exactly that behaviour within the standard, but it could do so partly.

There is no reason at all why a compiler could not optimise away the storage for the struct if that storage is never referenced. If the compiler gets its analysis right, then no program that you could write would ever be able to tell whether the storage exists or not.

However, the compiler cannot report a smaller sizeof() thereby. The standard is pretty clear that objects have to be big enough to hold the bits and bytes they contain (see for example 3.9/4 in N3797), and to report a sizeof smaller than that required to hold an int would be wrong.

At N3797 5.3.2:

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand

I do not se that 'representation' can change according to whether the struct or member is referenced.

As another way of looking at it:

```
struct A {
  int i;
};
struct B {
  int i;
};
A a;
a.i = 0;
assert(sizeof(A)==sizeof(B));
```

I do not see that this assert can be allowed to fail in a standards-conforming implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at templates, you'll notice that "optimization" of such often ends up with nearly nothing in the output even though the template files may be thousands of lines...

I think that the optimization you are talking about will nearly always occur in a function when the object is used on the stack and the object doesn't get copied or passed down to another function and the private field is never accessed (not even initialized... which could be viewed as a bug!)