# convenient Vector3f class

Tags: c++, c++20

Sometimes there is a need to have a `Vector3f` class, which has `x`, `y` and `z` members, and can be indexed as a `float[3]` array at the same time (there are several questions here at SO already about this).

Something like:

```
struct Vector3f {
    float data[3];
    float &x = data[0];
    float &y = data[1];
    float &z = data[2];
};
```

With this, we can write this:

```
Vector3f v;
v.x = 2.0f;
v.y = 3.0f;
v.z = 4.0f;
glVertex3fv(v.data);
```

But this implementation is bad, because references take space in the `struct` (which is quite unfortunate. I don't see any reason why references cannot be removed in this particular case, maybe it is missed optimization from the compiler's part).

But, with `[[no_unique_address]]` I had this idea:

```
#include <new>

template <int INDEX>
class Vector3fProperty {
    public:
        operator float() const {
            return propertyValue();
        }
        float &operator=(float value) {
            float &v = propertyValue();
            v = value;
            return v;
        }
    private:
        float &propertyValue() {
            return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<float*>(this))[INDEX];
        }
        float propertyValue() const {
            return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(this))[INDEX];
        }
};

struct Vector3f {
    [[no_unique_address]]
    Vector3fProperty<0> x;
    [[no_unique_address]]
    Vector3fProperty<1> y;
    [[no_unique_address]]
    Vector3fProperty<2> z;

    float data[3];
};

static_assert(sizeof(Vector3f)==12);
```

So, basically, I have properties in the `struct`, which handles the access to `x`, `y` and `z`. These properties should not take space, as they are empty, and have the attribute of `[[no_unique_address]]`

What do you think about this approach? Does it have UB?

---

Note, this question is about a class, for which all these are possible:

```
Vector3f v;
v.x = 1;
float tmp = v.x;
float *c = v.<something>; // there, c points to a float[3] array
```

Comment: I think this is UB. `[[no_unique_address]]` only means that the member **need not** have a unique address, not that it **must not** have a unique address. Also referencing parent class from a child looks fishy as well.

Comment: @freakish: ah, I missed this. If that's the case, this is the answer.

Comment: "this implementation is bad, because references take space in the struct" - and in *most* cases, that doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: and there are cases, where this matters **a lot**.

Comment: @geza So what you want is getters/setters which C++ does not support. Closest thing you can get is writing methods like `float& x() const;` and `void x(float);`.

Comment: why not have v.data[0], v.data[1], v.data[2] and v.x(), v.y(), v.z()?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Unhelpful comment is unhelpful. Just because there may be specific applications where tripling the size of your type doesn't matter doesn't mean you shouldn't care at all about the implementation of fundamental library components like this.

Comment: @Barry Of course you should care, in general. But in *my* experience; something like this is rarely the bottleneck. So better to just get on with your life and add value to your customers and then worry about this stuff if it *actually* shows up as a problem.

Comment: @slepic: because that's a function call. `v.x()=2.0f` looks ugly. `v.setX(2.0f)` is not as terse as it could be.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: okay. Let's suppose that I did this, and I found, that this is a bottleneck. Which is not too hard to imagine. Without references, this struct is 12 bytes. With references, it is 16+3*8 = you do the math (this is for 64 bit machines). If I have a lot of vectors, this can matter.

Comment: @geza *Of course* it can matter. I didn't say otherwise. I'm just saying that it *rarely* matters in most real-life programs. And when it doesn't, spending time on optimizing it is a waste of time that could be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: In this case, @JesperJuhl, I would personally assume it matters, on the grounds that "array of three `float`s and not `double`s, specifically named `x`, `y`, and `z`" is highly suggestive of 3D graphics.  It's thus likely to be used in a context where a large number of `Vector3f`s must be stored (to represent an object's vertices) and performance is extremely important (because it has to compete with other 3D graphics libraries), and thus essentially storing three pointers would be highly undesirable.

Comment: Those function calls aren't really different from `operator[]`, conceptually, but I agree that `v.x` would be more terse. The implementation may get even [uglier](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mcjISfnFoeOfkFdY) ;) , but some compilers seem to like [it](https://godbolt.org/z/Yj5W5Z) even more than the [easy](https://godbolt.org/z/hldG3Y) one.

Comment: @Bob__: there is no difference between the "ugly" and the "easy" one. Both compiles to "mov eax, 3; ret". It's just the `norm_2` isn't removed, as it is not a template.

Comment: (Mainly @JesperJuhl ) : Implementations can change. It's more important to have a *stable interface*. The crucial question therefore is: **If** this turns out to be a bottleneck, can the implementation be changed to something better, *without affecting client code*? The question refers to [`glVertex3fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml), but this is an ancient API. Nowadays, vertex data is stored in Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs), where the data layout *can* be far more complicated than that of a plain array anyhow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this implementation is bad, because references take space in the struct (which is quite unfortunate. I don't see any reason why references cannot be removed in this particular case, maybe it is missed optimization from the compiler's part).

This looks like a complicated issue. Standard-layout classes have to be compatible between each other. And so compilers are not allowed to eliminate any member, regardless of how they are defined. For non standard-layout? Who knows. For more info read this: [Do the C++ standards guarantee that unused private fields will influence sizeof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915630/do-the-c-standards-guarantee-that-unused-private-fields-will-influence-sizeof)

From my experience compilers never remove class members, even if they are "unused" (e.g. formally `sizeof` does use them).

> Does it have UB?

I think this is UB. First of all `[[no_unique_address]]` only means that the member **need not** have a unique address, not that it **must not** have a unique address. Secondly it is not clear where your `data` member starts. Again, compilers are free to use or not paddings of previous `[[no_unique_address]]` class members. Meaning your accessors may access incorrect piece of memory.

Another problem is that you want to access "outer" memory from the "inner" class. AFAIK such thing is also UB in C++.

> What do you think about this approach?

Assuming it is correct (which is not) I still don't like it. You want getters/setters but C++ does not support this feature. So instead of doing those weird, complicated constructs (imagine other people maintaining this code) how about simply do

```
struct Vector3f {
    float data[3];
    float x() {
        return data[0];
    }
    void x(float value) {
        data[0] = value;
    }
    ...
};
```

You say this code is ugly. Maybe it is. But it is simple, easy to read and maintain. There's no UB, it does not depend on potential hacks with unions, and does exactly what you want, except for beauty requirement. :)

Comment: You may be interested, I asked the "remove class member" part here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811424/is-it-a-missed-optimization-when-a-compile-time-known-reference-takes-space-in

Answer (score 5):

If this is going to live in a header, and you have some confidence in your compiler's optimizing capabilities, you can probably stick to a plain-old `operator[]()` overload and expect the compiler to be smart enough to elide the call and return the element that you want. E.g.:

```
class Vec3f {
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    float &operator[](int i) {
        if(i == 0) {
            return x;
        }
        if(i == 1) {
            return y;
        }
        if(i == 2) {
            return z;
        }
    }
};
```

I tossed this into Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/0X4FPL), which showed clang optimizing the `operator[]` call away at `-O2`, and GCC at `-O3`. Less exciting than your approach, but simple and should work under most circumstances.

Comment: Well, this will be optimized only when `i` is known at compile time, right? https://godbolt.org/z/evVGPZ

Comment: True! What you are getting in your example is definitely less efficient than the optimal. However, in most applications with a fixed-size array, I imagine it would be uncommon for there to be situations where a specific index cannot be known at compile time. Either an index will be supplied as a literal, or there will be loops over [0,2]. This is of course highly application sensitive, so the anonymous structs/unions proposed by @Xirema is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

## GLM implements this kind of functionality using anonymous `struct`s inside an anonymous `union`

I can't personally guarantee that this is standard-compliant, but most major compilers (MSVC, GCC, Clang) will support this idiom:

```
struct Vector3f {
    union {
        struct {
            float x, y, z;
        };
        struct {
            float data[3];
        };
    };
    Vector3f() : Vector3f(0,0,0) {}
    Vector3f(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

int main() {
    Vector3f vec;
    vec.x = 14.5;
    std::cout << vec.data[0] << std::endl; //Should print 14.5
    vec.y = -22.345;
    std::cout << vec.data[1] << std::endl; //Should print -22.345
    std::cout << sizeof(vec) << std::endl; //On most platforms will print 12
}
```

The non-standard behavior is in the anonymous struct used to group the letters together, which GCC will issue a warning about. As far as I know, the `union` itself should be valid, because the datatypes are all identical, but you should still check with your compiler documentation if you're unsure whether this is valid or not.

As an added convenience, we can also overload the brackets operator to shorten our syntax a little:

```
struct Vector3f {
    /*...*/
    float& operator[](size_t index) {return data[index];}
    float operator[](size_t index) const {return data[index];}
};



int main() {
    Vector3f vec;
    vec.x = 14.5;
    std::cout << vec[0] << std::endl; //Should print 14.5
    vec.y = -22.345;
    std::cout << vec[1] << std::endl; //Should print -22.345
    std::cout << sizeof(vec) << std::endl; //On most platforms will print 12
}
```

---

Just for clarity, accessing inactive members in the way I am is valid according to the C++ standard, because those members share a "common subsequence":

> If two union members are standard-layout types, it's well-defined to examine their common subsequence on any compiler.
>
> [CPP Reference: Union Declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

Because `x` and `data[0]` are

- Both `float`s,
- Both occupy the same memory,
- Are both standard Layout types as the standard defines them,

It's perfectly valid to access one or the other regardless of which is currently active.

Comment: This is UB. C++ (unlike C) does not allow accessing other union members once initialized with one.

Comment: @freakish It does if (and only if) the types of the inactive union members are the same as the active members and occupy the same memory.

Comment: @Xirema it is technically UB from a standards perspective. However AFAIK all compilers have chosen to define the behavior for compatibility reasons (within reason). Unless you're thinking that "compatible types" makes this OK...

Comment: @freakish: I think xirema is right. There is a additional clause in the standard, that permits this case.

Comment: it's UB and uses two GNU extensions  a) anonymous struct not allowed by ISO . b) union type punning works. Not ALL compilers support that, but GNU collections works in non-strict mode. Xinera misquotes clause, because it relates to stucts with common begin, which isn't the case here.

Comment: this is UB according to standard.

Comment: @Xirema your anonymous struct and `float[3]` **do not** have common struct subsequence. Come on.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie There is no type-punning in this code. The anonymous struct is however non-ISO, agreed.

Comment: common sequence doesn't apply here.. it would have applied if both members  were  standard-layout ctypes with equivalent declarations. Either two arrays or two structs. SO it's technically type punning, because way how array is aligned may be (platform defined) different from struct.. especially if certain pragmas were used in code.

Comment: @Xirema also that piece of standard **does not** imply that you can cast one to another. It only means that you can examine them (possibly independently).

Comment: @freakish But there's no casting in this code. A `float` is always being treated like a `float`.

Comment: @Xirema I meant casting array to anonymous struct. Shortcut, you know what I mean. Type-punning.

Comment: Found the confusion: forgot to wrap `data` inside its own struct. Should be good now.

Comment: @Xirema still UB. Compilers are allowed to add padding between members. Although I agree, most won't in this case (which makes the case special, we don't like special). I wonder if with `__attribute__((packed))` (or equivalent) this is ok. Although it does look unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: It may be worth comparing to `std::complex`, it's probably the closest guaranteed-compliant example to your code.  (For comparison, `std::complex<T>` requires `T` to be one of the three floating-point types, and is required by the standard to have a layout identical to `T[2]` with no padding or other members, to guarantee layout compatibility with C's `T _Complex`.)  It doesn't use a union or type punning, though.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this is impossible: pointer arithmetic is defined only within an array, and there’s no way (without putting a reference in the class, which takes up space in current implementations) to have `v.x` refer to an array element.