# Is it a missed optimization, when a compile-time known reference takes space in a non-aggregate struct?

Tags: c++, struct, reference, initialization, language-lawyer

Note: this is a follow-up question to: [Is it a missed optimization, when a compile-time known reference takes space in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811230/is-it-a-missed-optimization-when-a-compile-time-known-reference-takes-space-in), which showed that aggregate initialization can replace the default initialization of `b` as a reference to `a` by making it a reference to some other variable. This question is about what happens when aggregate initialization is *not* a possibility.

See this example:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int &b;

    Foo() : b(a) { }
};
```

Is it a missed optimization, if `sizeof(Foo)!=sizeof(int)`?

I mean, can the compiler remove `b` from the struct, as it always refers to `a`?

Is there anything which stops the compiler to make this transformation?

(Note, `struct Foo` looks as it is. No additional constructors, etc. But you can add anything around `Foo`, which shows that this optimization would violate the standard)

Comment: What's the point of duplicating your question?

Comment: @SergeyA: this is not the same question.

Comment: @SergeyA: This question is for non-aggregate structs (in this case, having an explicit constructor), vs. the previous question which was about "plain" aggregate structs. Not enough of a C++ guru to say how important the distinction is. Does seem like there is a difference; an aggregate struct can initialize `b` to reference some other variable, but a struct that can only be constructed via a constructor that denies the caller the ability to initialize `b` to something else might be optimizable.

Comment: Ok, I missed that part, when I voted to close, there was no indication that it is a follow-up. I think, it would make sense if you would indicate the difference upfront.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It's important because the answer to the previous question assumes the type is an aggregate so it is not applicable here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yeah, I updated the comment to indicate that. I also edited the question to make it clear how this question differs based on the answer to the last question; if geza disagrees with my wording, please personalize it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: thanks, I'm fine with your edit.

Comment: Constructors, like all member functions, can be defined out of line, but the size and layout of the class must be known as soon as the class definition is seen. So having such an "optimization" would mean that the size and layout of a class can change depending on whether a constructor - any constructor - is defined inside its definition or outside. That's...not ideal.

Comment: @T.C.: thanks, your comment is very valuable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the following example `y.b` refers to `x.a`.

```
int main ()
{
    Foo     x;
    Foo     y(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well now we need a followup question on what happens if we prevent the copy/move/assignment operators from being generated (or implement them all explicitly to prevent the issue). :-)

Comment: Then I'd need to ask a 3rd question, but I think I'll leave it to someone else/later...

Comment: @ShadowRanger: exactly! :)

Comment: @geza, I'll extend my answer to cover that case, too :- )

Comment: @geza In any case, these two questions go to show that in the case that was being discussed about the vector `class` the optimization is probably not possible. Edit : But it also shows that using reference members that way is likely to lead to trouble! They might not be aliases to what you expect.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: yes. I've never used them, that's why I don't think about these issues.

Comment: @geza, Sorry, I just figured out that the reason I was going to base my answer on, is invalid. I was going to say that anyone could have created a layout-compatible class with arbitrary constructor, but I forgot that a reference member instantly renders a class non-standard-layout...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, implicit swap and assignment could present even a bigger surprise to an uncautious user of a reference data member...

Comment: @IgorG: Good to know, thanks for the info! It seems that it may take a significant effort to optimize away these references, that's why it's not done.

Comment: @geza perhaps, you should stop asking the wrong question. Just ask “*under which circumstances is the optimization […] possible?*” Then, you don’t need to open a new question for each scenario, just to find out that it is not possible.